# Custom Notifications not working on BatchApexErrorEvents

Tags: apex, batch, platform-event, notification

When long-running batches fail I want the starting user to be notified in the org using Custom Notifications.

Therefore I added the marker-interface `Database.RaisesPlatformEvents` to the Batch class

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful, Database.RaisesPlatformEvents {
   ...
}
```

created a trigger

```
trigger BatchApexErrorEvents on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {
    new HandleBatchErrors(Trigger.new).execute();
}
```

which delegates to

```
public with sharing class HandleBatchErrors {

   ...

    public void execute() {
        for(BatchApexErrorEvent event : events) {
            Messaging.CustomNotification notification = new Messaging.CustomNotification();
            notification.setNotificationTypeId(typeID);
            notification.setTitle('title');
            notification.setTargetId('000000000000000AAA');
            ...
            notification.send(userId)
        }
    }
}
```

But no notifications show up. I see the errors in the `Apex Job Logs` but that's all.

Comment: implying that Automated Process user is not permitted to send Custom Notifications?

Comment: I don’t get you...

Comment: the trigger runs in user context = `Automated Process` user; Winter 21 requires user to have specific permission: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notif_builder_considerations.htm&type=5; is it possible that Automated Process user doesn't have this permission?

Comment: Whats the value of userId? The autoproc user the event trigger runs as? Or the user that the batch job was running as?

Comment: The user that kicked of the batch @ca_peterson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint given by Chris Peterson in the comment helped me solve it. It was the userId used in

```
notification.send(userId);
```

It was set to `UserInfo.getUserId()` which in the context of the BatchApexErrorEvent trigger was an Automated Process. When I changed it to the user that kicked of the Batch by querying

```
[SELECT CreatedById FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id event.AsyncApexJobId]

notification.send(job.CreatedById);
```

everything worked out just fine.

Comment: Woohoo! glad it helped. I was just starting to hunt down who owns this in case it didn't.

Comment: @Robert Can you please explain how can we get the value of `event.AsyncApexJobId` in query written by you

Comment: It’s a field on the event which is available in triggers.